# How to pass "none" to -audioval when running qemu-system-arm on Ubuntu WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, qemu

I'm trying to run qemu-system-arm Versatilepb emulator with the following command:

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel t.bin -serial mon:stdio
```

but whenever I do that, I get an error that my ALSA lib isn't installed:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5220:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
alsa: Could not initialize DAC
alsa: Failed to open `default':
alsa: Reason: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5220:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
alsa: Could not initialize DAC
alsa: Failed to open `default':
alsa: Reason: No such file or directory
audio: Failed to create voice `lm4549.out'
qemu-system-arm: could not load kernel 't.bin'
```

So I've read that I need to either install ALSA, PA, OSS, or some other form of audio drivers if I want to emulate that specific board. I also saw that I can ignore those errors if I purposely set the audio driver to be none, and that's what I tried doing by trying out the following:

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel t.bin -serial mon:stdiocode -audiodev none,id=none
```

that returns this:

```
audio: Device lm4549: audiodev default parameter is deprecated, please specify audiodev=none
```

I've tried looking around, but there's a handful of email threads pertaining to maintainers of qemu who are familiar with the -audiodev parameter, but none seem to be just running the emulator with "none" as the audio-driver. What am I doing wrong or how would I go fixing this, without having to install one of the above-mentioned audio driver libs?